# How do I increase display saturation?

Tags: display, amdgpu

I am currently trying to increase the saturation/vibrance of my display, since the colours look pretty washed out. On Windows this could be achieved through the AMD Catalyst Control Center, but I do not have access to it in Ubuntu. I have tried using Xrandr, but no option for this appears. I want to set saturation manually, is there any tool for it? Thanks.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/07/25/ubuntu-20-10-groovy-gorilla-end-of-life-reached-on-july-22-2021/ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Answer (score 0):

You should add an ICC file in Settings > Color > your_screen.

There are two ways of obtaining the ICC color profile. First, you could purchase a screen calibrator device and generate it, but this might be an expensive option. Second, if you have a bit of luck, you can find one on the internet that suits your screen. I did not find any ICC editors to create it manually.